# Scientific Plotting in Python

Tags: python, visualization, plot, scientific-computing

I have a large data set of tuples containing (time of event, latitude, longitude) that I need to visualize. I was hoping to generate a 'movie'-like xy-plot, but was wondering if anyone has a better idea or if there is an easy way to do this in Python?

Thanks in advance for the help,
--Leo

Comment: such a general title ^^ good way to get 6k views and be automatically suggested

Answer (score 16, accepted):

get [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net)

Comment: I thought that only made static plots. Is there a way to make movies out of a series of plots?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a close enough to what you're looking for, but <a href="http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/">these examples</a> gives you a constantly-updating rendering in a wx frame.

I suspect it would be helpful to know what kind of animated output you're looking for, exactly.

Comment: Erm, not sure what happened to that link. Try this one:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/

Comment: you can also make a movie out of a series of plots using something like mencoder.

Comment: plotly and dash are also cool

Answer (score 8):

The easiest option is matplotlib.  Two particular solutions that might work for you are:

1) You can generate a series of plots, each a snapshot at a given time.  These can either be displayed as a dynamic plot in matplotlib, where the axes stay the same and the data moves around; or you can save the series of plots to separate files and later combine them to make a movie (using a separate application).  There a number of examples in the official examples for doing these things.

2) A simple scatter plot, where the colors of the circles changes with time might work well for your data.  This is super easy.  See [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_collection.html), for example, which produces this figure
[alt text http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/plot_directive/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_collection.hires.png](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/plot_directive/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_collection.hires.png)

Answer (score 4):

I'd try rpy. All the power of R, from within python.
http://rpy.sourceforge.net/

rpy is awesome.

Check out the CRAN library for animations,
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html

Of course, you have to learn a bit about R to do this, but if you're planning to do this kind of thing routinely in future it will be well worth your while to learn.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in scientific plotting using Python then have a look at Mlab: http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/mlab.html

It allows you to plot 2d / 3d and animate your data and the quality of the charts is really high.

Answer (score 2):

Enthought's [Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/chaco/) is designed for interactive/updating plots.  the api and such takes a little while to get use to, but once you're there it's a fantastic framework to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I have had reasonable success with Python applications generating SVG with animation features embedded, but this was with a smaller set of elements than what you probably have.  For example, if your data is about a seismic event, show a circle that shows up when the event happened and grows in size matching the magnitude of the event.  A moving indicator over a timeline is really simple to add.

[Kaleidoscope](http://www.kevlindev.com/samples/kaleidoscope/kaleidoscope.svg) (Opera, others maybe, Safari not) shows lots of pieces moving around and I found inspirational.  Lots of other good SVG tutorial content on the site too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [PyQwt](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/). It's a plotting library which works with Qt/PyQt.

Several of the PyQwt examples (in the qt4examples directory) show how to create "moving" / dynamically changing plots -- look at `CPUplot.py`, `MapDemo.py`, `DataDemo.py`.

Comment: PyQwt is nice but it gave me so much (compilation) troubles on Windows and Mac that I ended up using matplotlib